# Laravel eloquent group by with 3-table join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've been hacking away at this for hours, but can't work out how to resolve it.

Table structures are:

Plans:

- id
- title

Features:

- id
- title

FeatureTerms:

- id
- text
- plan_id
- feature_id

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
[{
  "plan_id": 1,
  "title": "Plan 1",
  "features": [
    {
      "title": "Feature 1",
      "term": "Term 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Feature 2",
      "term": "Term 2"
    } 
  ]
},{
  ...
}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Regards,
Andy

Comment: Does Plans and Features have ManytoMany relationship or OnetoMany relationship?

Comment: Plans->FeatureTerms = 1:many
Features->FeatureTerms = 1:1

I also just solved the issue, but appreciate your response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It was more straightforward than I thought:

```
$plans = Plan::with("featureTerms.feature")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define [**Has Many Through**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship on `Plan` like this

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Features::class, FeatureTerms::class);
}
```

After you have define relationship you can return plan with features eager loaded like this

```
$plan = Plan::with(["features"])->first();
```

This will return the first plan with related features

Answer (score 0):

You can group by three tables join, simply enter columns names according you want to groupBy, as many column you want :

```
$query->groupBy(['column_name','column_name'...])->get();
```